# form is empty but every time I refresh, previous result is submitted.

Tags: python, django

so I'm implementing commenting system. The problem I'm having is with commenting on a comment. Users are able to reply to comment, and when the user submits info to reply form and click reply button then reply is submitted to both commenting section and reply section. And when I refresh the page, that reply comment is again displayed on the commenting section. if I refresh again, then I now have three same reply on my commenting section when there should be only one reply in reply section not commenting.  Sorry if this is too wordy.
This is my code: 
views.py

```
def post(request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
        try:
            profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
            # profile = request.user.myprofile
        except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            profile = None


        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        post.save()      # and save it

        path = request.get_full_path()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
        #comments = post.comment_set.all()
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
            parent_comment = None
            if parent_id is not None:
                try:
                    parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
                except:
                    parent_comment = None
            comment_text = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=request.get_full_path(),
                text=comment_text,
                post = post,
                parent = parent_comment
                )

            comment_form = CommentForm()
        for c in comments:
            c.get_children()
        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'profile' :profile,
            'comments' : comments,
            'comment_form':comment_form

        }

        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

and in my models.py for comment I have

```
def get_children(self):
        if self.is_child:
            return None
        else:
            return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

then post.html

```
<h1>Comments/Questions</h1>
<form method="POST" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ comment_form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Add comment'/>
</form>


<br/>
<hr/>
<table class='table'>

{% for comment in comments %}

<tr><td>{{ comment.get_comment }} 
<br/><small>via {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago </small>
        {% if not comment.is_child %}
        <ul>
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
        <li>{{ child.get_comment }} 
        <small>via {{ child.user }}</small>


        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <a href='#' class='reply_btn'>Reply</a>
        <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Add reply'/>
        </form>
        </div>
        {% endif %}


</td></tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>

</div>



<div class = "col-sm-3">

</div>

    {% include 'footer.html' %}



<script>
{% block jquery %}
$('.reply_btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".reply_comment").fadeToggle();
  // $(".reply_comment").fadeToggle();
})
{% endblock %}
</script>
```

I think the problem is in my views.py but not sure what's wrong....any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: that's how html+post works. if you have a form, submit it, then refresh the page you get after submitting, you're RE-SUBMITTING the form, causing another post, blah blah blah. you need to go a GET-POST-REDIRECT instead, so that whatever page the post generates becomes a 'get' page instead.

Comment: @MarcB hmm I thought that's what I'm doing...can I ask you where you see the problem?

Comment: I don't see any redirect, just re-rendering "main/post.html".

Comment: your problem should be in your view

Comment: the two forms actions are ""

Comment: @Transformer yes I see that, but even after fixing that by adding    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url()) I get the reply in my commenting section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent duplicate form submission you should implement the 
[`Post/Redirect/Get` Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

So if the form submission is valid and you performed all data manipulation redirect to the empty form page:

```
def post(request, slug):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
    ...
    ...
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        # do you data manipulation
        ...
        # redirect to the empty form view
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/url_of_empty_form/')
    ...

    # this will only render if the form is not valid
    return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I tried adding return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url()). While it fixes one issue;refreshing forces another submission, I still have the problem that is reply is being shown in the commenting section as well. For example, if I have comment "hello" then put reply "hi"...then the reply "hi" is shown and "hi" is again shown as a comment...can you please tell me why this is occuring....